# Accessing variables from separate files in java and performing sum operation on them

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface

I've created a program for touch based interactive pizza house in which i have created three files separately for mainmenu(pizza.java) menu for pizza base(pizzabase.java) and menu for selecting toppings(pizzatoppings.java).
The Problem is that when i access the button view amount in first file(main menu) i need to get the sum of the **basecost** variable and the **toppingcost** variable which are in two different files pizzabase.java and pizzatoppings.java.how can i sum the basecost and toppingcost presnt in two different files and display it in the first file(pizza.java).can somebody suggest a suitable answer.

This is the first file pizza.java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class p extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


JLabel l,l1;
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
Font f1,f;


    p(String q)
    {   
    super(q);
    Container cc=getContentPane();
    cc.setLayout(null);
    f1=new Font("Century",1,27);
    l=new JLabel("PIZZA HOUSE");
    cc.add(l);

    l.setFont(f1);
    l.setBounds(250,30,250,50);

    f=new Font("Arial",1,17);
    l1=new JLabel("MAIN MENU");
    cc.add(l1);
    l1.setFont(f);
    l1.setBounds(300,70,100,50);

    b1=new JButton("BASE");
    cc.add(b1);
    b1.setBounds(250,130,200,50);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

    b2=new JButton("TOPPINGS");
    cc.add(b2);
    b2.setBounds(250,190,200,50);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    b3=new JButton("VIEW AMOUNT");
    cc.add(b3);
    b3.setBounds(250,250,200,50);
    b3.addActionListener(this);

    b4=new JButton("PAY BILL");
    cc.add(b4);
    b4.setBounds(250,310,200,50);
    b4.addActionListener(this);


    b5=new JButton("EXIT");
    cc.add(b5);
    b5.setBounds(250,370,200,50);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    }



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t)
{   
    if(t.getSource()==b1)
    {
        p1 obj=new p1("Pizza Base");
        obj.setSize(400,350);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(200,200);
        this.setVisible(false);     
    }


    if(t.getSource()==b2)
    {
        p2 obj=new p2("Pizza-Toppings");
        obj.setSize(500,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(200,200);
        this.setVisible(false); 
    }

    if(t.getSource()==b3)
    {}

    if(t.getSource()==b4)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"AMOUNT RECEIVED!!!!","THANK YOU",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    if(t.getSource()==b5)
    {
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

     }
}

class pizza
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    p obj=new p("Pizza-House");
    obj.setSize(700,500);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setLocation(200,200);
}
}
```

This is the second file pizzabase.java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;


class p1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JLabel l;
JButton b1,b2;
JRadioButton R1,R2;
Font f1;
Connection con;
Statement stat;
String qry;
int Soft=30;
int Hard=40;
int baseCost=0;




    p1(String q)
    {   
    super(q);
    Container cc=getContentPane();
    cc.setLayout(null);
    f1=new Font("Century",1,16);
    l=new JLabel("SELECT BASE");
    cc.add(l);
    l.setFont(f1);
    l.setBounds(130,30,150,50);

    R1=new JRadioButton("SOFT--Rs.30");
    cc.add(R1);
    R1.setBounds(140,100,200,50);
    R1.addActionListener(this);
    R1.setSelected(false);

    R2=new JRadioButton("HARD--Rs.40");
    cc.add(R2);
    R2.setBounds(140,150,200,50);
    R2.addActionListener(this);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(R1);
    group.add(R2);

    b1=new JButton("CANCEL");
    cc.add(b1);
    b1.setBounds(120,200,150,30);
    b1.addActionListener(this);



    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t)
{   


        if(R1.isSelected())
        {

        baseCost+=Soft;

        System.out.println("Total Amount=Rs."+baseCost);
        p obj=new p("Pizza-House");
        obj.setSize(700,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(200,200);
        this.setVisible(false);
        }




    if(R2.isSelected())
    {
        baseCost+=Hard;
        System.out.println("Total Amount=Rs."+baseCost);
        p obj=new p("Pizza-House");
        obj.setSize(700,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(200,200);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }



    if(t.getSource()==b1)
        {
        p obj=new p("Pizza-House");
        obj.setSize(700,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(200,200);
        this.setVisible(false);
        }
}
}

class pizzabase
{
public static void main(String args[])

{
    p1 obj=new p1("Pizza Base");
    obj.setSize(400,350);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setLocation(200,200);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

This is the third file pizzatoppings.java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class p2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {

JLabel l,l1;
JButton b1,b2;
Font f,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5;
JCheckBox c1,c2,c3,c4;
int Tomato=10;
int Capsicum=15;
int Onion=20;
int Paneer=30;



    p2(String q)
    {   
    super(q);
    Container cc=getContentPane();
    cc.setLayout(null);
    f1=new Font("Century",1,27);
    l=new JLabel("SELECT TOPPINGS");
    cc.add(l);
    l.setFont(f1);
    l.setBounds(110,30,350,50);

    f=new Font("Arial",1,17);
    l1=new JLabel("SUB MENU");
    cc.add(l1);
    l1.setFont(f);
    l1.setBounds(190,70,100,50);

    c1=new JCheckBox("Tomato-Rs.10");
    cc.add(c1);
    f2=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c1.setFont(f2);
    c1.setBounds(170,120,300,50);
    c1.addActionListener(this);

    c2=new JCheckBox("Capsicum-Rs.15");
    cc.add(c2);
    f3=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c2.setFont(f3);
    c2.setBounds(170,190,300,50);
    c2.addActionListener(this);

    c3=new JCheckBox("Onion-Rs.20");
    cc.add(c3);
    f4=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c3.setFont(f4);
    c3.setBounds(170,260,300,50);
    c3.addActionListener(this);

    c4=new JCheckBox("Paneer-Rs.30");
    cc.add(c4);
    f5=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c4.setFont(f5);
    c4.setBounds(170,330,300,50);
    c4.addActionListener(this);

    b2=new JButton("OK");
    cc.add(b2);
    b2.setBounds(100,400,100,50);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    b1=new JButton("Cancel");
    cc.add(b1);
    b1.setBounds(300,400,100,50);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    }



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t)
{              


    int toppingCost=0;
                 if (c1.isSelected())
        toppingCost +=Tomato ;
                 if (c2.isSelected())
        toppingCost += Capsicum;
                if (c3.isSelected())
        toppingCost += Onion;
                 if (c4.isSelected())
        toppingCost += Paneer;
    if(t.getSource()==b2)
    {
    System.out.println("Total Amount=Rs."+ toppingCost);
    p obj=new p("Pizza-House");
    obj.setSize(700,500);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setLocation(200,200);
    this.setVisible(false);

    }

    if(t.getSource()==b1)
    {   
        p obj=new p("Pizza-House");
        obj.setSize(700,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(200,200);
        this.setVisible(false);

    }

     }
}

 class pizzatoppings{

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    p2 obj=new p2("Pizza-Toppings");

    obj.setSize(500,500);

    obj.setVisible(true);

    obj.setLocation(200,200);

    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  But really, this question is OOP 101, which people should get sorted before they ever attempt GUI programming..

Comment: Separate your view from your data, create one or models for you data, which can be shared amongst your views...

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) `f=new Font("Arial",1,17);` instead of that, use something that will work on all OS, and don't use 'magic numbers'.  To correct both, change it to `f=new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.PLAIN,17);`

Comment: can i use a common package for all files?